# Best approach to redesign a mobile homepage with both existing and new features?

Tags: mobile-application, homepage

I'm currently working on an existing application whereby,
 1. I'll need to redesign the homepage 
 2. New core features will be added to it

Now this work is for a client that I'm working it and they are requesting a for a concept for the homepage. What's the best approach in the UX field to work on this?

I did work on an Information Architecture but I don't find it useful since the new features haven't been worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Map out your user types / personas, their pains and tasks. Use those requirements + your navigation to lay out a narrative in the HP which progressively explains what the product / service is.

Lastly, after you have an initial mockup, put it into a tool such as UsabilityHub and ask users what they think your product or service does.

An example to gather some ideas from: 
https://uxdesign.cc/designing-a-homepage-for-8-million-students-of-all-ages-e299fff637d2